# displaying the php server validations after clicking Ok of jquery dialog box confirmation

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP Form which contains Some Input Fields and Select Tags and Multiple File Uploads, so on submission i need to see the preview of the form including images in a jquery dialog modal confirmation box.  The PHP Form has Server Side Validations, so after form preview , my form is not displaying the validations after Clicking Ok of the dialog box.

```
$('#submit_form').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $("span#dialog-source").html($("select#source_details").val());
        $("span#dialog-inc-title").html($("select#title_emp").val());
        $("span#dialog-inc-date").html($("input#demo1").val());
        $("span#dialog-inc-detail").html($("textarea#incident").val()); 

        var sub_val = $("input[name='process']").val();
        if(sub_val == "Submit") {
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );           
        }
        else {              
            $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "close" );
        }

    }); 
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 550,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $('#myform').submit();
                //return false;
                //$( this ).dialog( "close" );
            },
            Cancel: function() {                    
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Marcel After Form Submission , the dialog box gets prompt for the preview of the values and i want the Ok button of the dialog box to submit the form and also it should display the errors if any field's value is not properly inserted